# Python: trying to collapse a function mapping on the second argument

Tags: python, functional-programming

NOTE: Please read the BETTER UPDATE section below before commenting.  There is some subtlety here.  None of the answers given yet work in context, as far as I can tell.

I'm trying to find an analog to the python 'map' function with slightly different functionality.  This is best explained by example.  The 'map' function does the following:

```
In [1]:    def f(x,y):
               return x+y
In [2]:    map(f, ['a','b','c'],['1','2','3'])

Out[2]:    ['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
```

So, map turns f into a new function, let's call it f_zipper. f_zipper zips its arguments and applies f to each zipped pair.

What I'd like to build is a function that I'll call 'magical_map' that behaves as follows:

```
In [1]:    def f(x,y):
               return x+y
In [2]:    magical_map(f, ['a','b','c'],'1')

Out[2]:    ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
```

So magical_map makes a bunch of calls to f (one for each element in the first argument list), but it collapses them all onto the second argument.

Note: I need a truly functional solution, so to speak, because I won't have access to the second argument.

i.e. what I'm going to do later on is build the following function:

```
intermed_func = functools.partial(magical_map, f)
final_func = functools.partial(intermed_func, arg_I_know)
```

then final_func can be called as

```
final_func(last_min_arg)
```

and return

```
[f(arg_I_know[0], last_min_arg), f(arg_I_know[1], last_min_arg), ...]
```

I'm basically stumped on how to build 'magical_map'.  Any help would be great. I haven't had a lot of luck finding anything on this subject.

Thanks!

BETTER UPDATE:

Solving the problem in context is much harder than simply writing a function that works when both arguments are known at once.  The problem is, they are not known in this context.  More precisely, I need to be able to make the following 'final_func' apply split to all three strings.  Right now, using 'map' gives the following behavior.

```
def splitfunc(string, arg):
    return string.split(arg)

intermed_func = functools.partial(map, splitfunc)
final_func = functools.partial(intermed_func, ["a_b","v_c","g,g"])

final_func("_")

Out[xx]: [['a', 'b'], ['v_c'], ['g,g']]
```

but when I define magical_map as suggested (in all ways below) I get either errors or incorrect behavior.  For example.

```
def magical_map(func, mylist, arg):
   return map(f, mylist, [arg]*len(mylist))
```

then I run:

```
intermed_func = functools.partial(magical_map, splitfunc)
final_func = functools.partial(intermed_func, ["a_b","v,c","g,g"])

final_func("_")
```

I get:

```
['a_b_', 'v,c_', 'g,g_']
```

Comment: Nope, using 2.7.  I can't see how to develop the loop easily in context, but I'll think about it.

Comment: P.S. sorry for deleting the comment.  I'm new to Stack Overflow and apparently I'm a web form dumba$$.

Comment: Comments get deleted by their owners all the time.  Don't worry about that ... :)

Comment: Really? My solution seems to work perfectly in that context. You do have some typos, so maybe that's the problem. `magical_map` needs to use `map(func...`, not `map(f...`. Also, note that your list of values that need to be split has inconsistent middle elements (one `_` and two `,`'s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this lazy version:

```
>>> def add(x,y):
...     return x+y
... 
>>> def magic_map(func,*args):
...     return itertools.starmap(func,itertools.izip(*args))  #just zip in python 3.
...
>>> list(magic_map(add,['a', 'b', 'c'], itertools.repeat('1')))
['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
```

Note that we require the `zip` to take the shorter of the two series so that we can pass an infinite iterable to either argument which allows us to expand one using `itertools.repeat`.  This evaluates lazily as well, so I suppose that you could even pass 2 infinite iterables and it would work OK -- Provided you don't try to actually iterate over the entire returned object ;-)

---

Here's an attempt to use this in a context similar to what you're doing (although I don't completely understand what you're doing, so this could be way off):

```
import itertools
import functools

def magic_map(func,*args):
    return itertools.starmap(func,itertools.izip(*args))  #just zip in python 3.

lst = ["a_b","v_c","g,g"]
print list(magic_map(str.split, lst, itertools.repeat('_')))

intermed_func = functools.partial(magic_map,str.split)
print list(intermed_func(lst ,itertools.repeat('_')))

final_func = functools.partial(intermed_func,lst)
print list(final_func(itertools.repeat('_')))
```

Output is:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['v', 'c'], ['g,g']]
[['a', 'b'], ['v', 'c'], ['g,g']]
[['a', 'b'], ['v', 'c'], ['g,g']]
```

which is what you want (I think).

Comment: +1, missed this one, the solution I would use. Much better not to rely on having a sequence.

Comment: I tried it, and this doesn't work in the application listed, because I don't know the second argument at the same time that I'm forced to pass the first argument.

Comment: @user1904822 -- I'm not sure what you mean.  Have a look at my edit and see if that helps you out at all -- also, thanks for helping me to figure out what `functools.partial` does ;-).  I've never needed it, so I've never bothered to learn it until now.

Comment: Nice, I think this one might work!  functools.partial is very cool, and I'm glad I found it too.  Basically, this functionality lets me write a generic container that automatically inherits all the methods from its elements.  When you call the element method on the container object, it returns a list of all results of the method on the elements.  (Think of this as the method getting distributed through the container bracket.) This will work for methods that take one argument.  I'm not sure how easy it will be to implement for methods with different numbers of arguments, though.  Still working.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3:

As usual, it's [`itertools` to the rescue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(map(f, ['a','b','c'], itertools.repeat("1")))
['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
```

For more than one value, use [`itertools.cycle()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

```
>>> list(map(f, ['a','b','c','d'], itertools.cycle("12")))
['a1', 'b2', 'c1', 'd2']
```

Comment: (+1) for `itertools.cycle()`, which I didn't know existed.

Comment: @NPE: Darn, and I just changed it to `itertools.repeat()` which makes more sense if there is just one parameter to be repeated...

Comment: unlike `zip`, `map` takes the longest argument

Comment: @thg435: Could you explain how this is relevant here? I must be missing something.

Comment: @TimPietzcker -- `itertools.repeat` will give you an iterable which is infinitely long ... So it is definitely the longest argument ;-).  You `map` will pair arguments to the function as:  `('a','1'), ('b','1'),('c','1'),(None,'1'),'(None,'1'),...`

Comment: Ah, I see. I tried this in Python 3, and there the iteration stops after the shortest iterable has been exhausted. (I just removed the call to `list()` needed in Python 3, and I had thought that would be sufficient to make it Python-2-compatible. My bad for not testing it twice.)

Comment: @TimPietzcker -- Interesting that they changed that behavior of `map` in python3.x -- Although the multi-argument form of `map` isn't very common in my experience.  It seems silly that there isn't a version independent way to do this.  Yours works with python3, mine with python2 -- Although mine is a little easier to port to python3 I think.  (change `itertools.izip` to just `zip`).  Sometimes I wish `itertools.izip` still existed in py3k and was just the builtin.  I feel like it would help with backward compatability.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.repeat`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat).

```
def magic_map(f, l, v):
    return map(f, l, itertools.repeat(v, len(l))
```

Use it like this:

```
>>> magic_map(f, ['a', 'b', 'c'], '1')
['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
```

**Edit:**

`map`, as [thg435](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884378/python-trying-to-collapse-a-function-mapping-on-the-second-argument/13884433#comment19125398_13884417) points out, goes until the longer argument is finished.

Comment: Have you tried this?  because I can't get it to work ... `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`

Comment: @mgilson Try it now -- I misunderstood how `map` worked with different-lengthed iterators.

Comment: I would argue the better option than giving the length of `l` to `repeat()` would be to do `starmap(f, zip(l, repeat(v)))`.

Comment: @Lattyware -- You'd be arguing for my answer then ;-) -- Of course in python2.x, you need `itertools.izip`, but that's just a small detail.

Comment: @SamMussmann -- This seems like it will work with a list as the first argument, but it won't work with arbitrary iterables.  (not all iterables have a well defined `len`).

Comment: Doesn't work in the sequence listed in the update.  Gives TypeError: takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
def magical_map(func, list, arg):
    return map(func, list, [arg]*len(list))
```

Actually, since that's a one-line function, might as well just write it out instead of defining it separately.

Comment: There's something funny with this solution in the larger context.  I'm posting a follow-up.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
from functools import partial
def map_with(f, it, **kwargs):
    return map(partial(f, **kwargs), it)

def f(x,y): 
    return x+y

print map_with(f, ['a', 'b', 'c'], y='1') # ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
```

Comment: Fails on the application listed (see the update to the comment).  I.e. when I define magical_map this way and then run the code in the update, I get TypeError: magical_map() takes exactly 2 arguments.